# derivative calculation is more efficient than the integration calculation

Tags: integration, derivatives

I read that for $n$ sampled time points, the computation time required by the derivative calculation increases linearly with $n$, while the computation time required by the integral calculation is proportional to $n^2$.

Can anyone explain why this happen?

Comment: You desperately need to give more context.

Answer (score 0):

Let's use a simple case of an $n$th order derivative (left, right, central doesn't matter). The basic form is:
$$\frac{d^n x(t)}{dt^n}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N} x_i*\alpha_i}{h^n}$$
Where $h$ is the (uniform) step size, and $\alpha$ are the various weights which are known constants depending on the order of the derivative, and "handedness". As can be clearly seen, the results here increase linearly with $N$, which is the number of sampled points.

For the integral, I'm not too sure, because there are so many different numerical integration methods. If you want to calculate an integral using trapezoid rule, it's a method which increases linearly:
$$\int x(t)dt=\sum_{i=1}^{N-1} \frac{x_i+x_{i+1}}{2}*h$$
It's not very accurate for larger stepsizes ($h$), but it does work, and it's complexity is nominally $O(N)=2N$.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_coefficient
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation